# Adding Custom Headers in Swagger UI- C#

Tags: swagger-ui

I am using Swagger UI in our Web API project. I have a requirement now to add a customized header for sending the Access Token for every Web API call through Swagger UI. I searched online and found two solutions for this.

1. I can add the custom Headers through Javascript code as mentioned here.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/ibuoVSYi9dw

But the problem I faced is, I need to get the Access Token value from Web.Config. The Code mentioned here needs to be added in the .JS file, which can't read Web.Config values. If I want to write this code in any other page where can I write it?

2. I can add the custom Headers through C# code as mentioned here.

http://ambracode.com/index/show/178414

But the problem I faced here is, by adding the above code new parameter textbox is shown in the Swagger UI. So for every Web API call I need to give the Access Token value in the textbox to make the request. But my requirement is to retrieve the value from Web.Config instead.

Can anyone give any suggestions on how to implement custom headers in the Swagger UI?